# Change the behavior of Org-mode auto expand relative path in link

Tags: org-mode

For example:

```
- modes/mu4e/mu4e.org
      `-data/images/kk.png
```

in file `mu4e.org`, when insert link with `[C-c C-l]`, the link
`file:../data/images/kk.png` will auto expand to
`file:~/Org/Emacs/modes/data/images/kk.png`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value of `org-link-file-path-type` is `adaptive`, which means make relative links if the link is to the current directory below, otherwise fully qualify the link.

You can force it to always be relative like so:

```
(setq org-link-file-path-type 'relative)
```

You can fully-qualify links on a link-by-link basis by passing one universal argument <kbd>C-u</kbd>.

Comment: If I force to use relative links, will org export links with relative url?

Comment: Or the default value adaptive links like file:~/Org/Emacs/modes/data/images/kk.png will exported as correct url path?

Comment: Can also be achieved via `M-x customize`.